# How to use Flow to get the User who edited a particular field?

Tags: visual-workflow, case

I am trying to build a record-triggered flow that will capture the name of the user who edits a particular field, "Case Reason."

Essentially, a Case can have several owners during its lifetime but I need to capture the Case's first owner. The first case owner always changes "Case Reason."

I created a new field called "Intake User" for the flow to update. I have created a record-triggered flow that will run when "Case Reason" is changed and "Intake User" is null.

I need help with what needs to come next... I think I need to create a Get Records element but I have no idea if it's possible to grab the name of the user who edited the Case Reason and how to do so. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: you need to 1) ensure field history tracking is enabled for Case Reason and 2) have flow query (Get Records) the `CaseHistory` object to see the list of changes over time

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need a Get Records element if you are updating the same record that triggered the flow; the flow will automatically have those values.

To update your field to show the person who is editing the Case Reason field, you should be able to use '$User.Username' $User should be available and contains details of the 'running user' of the flow.

You can add an assignment element to your flow, and assign the $User.Username to your case reason field.

[image: add user field to assignment]